# Создания бота на дискорд python

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делаю ботов для дискорда c помощью библиотеки discord.py. Я хочу сделать чтобы команда: .command (названия команды) (код команды) запоминалась и работала. Так же мне надо сделать угадай цифру. Помогите с реализацией.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Команда для кика участника сервера
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Kick",
    description=f"Kick user { member.mention }",
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = bot.user.name, icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url )
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Использование:

```
(ваш префикс)kick @пользователь
```

Команда для задавания префикса - поместить на самый верх, после `import discord`:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='тут префикс')
bot.remove_command( 'help' )
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен будет ли это работать, но всё же.

На счёт угадай цыфру, (если я всё правильно понял) можно сделать так:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('цыфра сгенерирована, угадайте ёё')
    x = randint()
    if randint in msg:
        await ctx.send('вы угадали!')
```